# TCP: switch to redundant machine, RST not sent immediately

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

consider the following scenario:

2 machines available - A and B **(both running on Linux)**

A is active.

B is not active.

host x is using TCP to talk with machine A.

everything works fine.

switchover happends - now machine B is active (uses same IP as machine A was using)
machine A is not active.

now host x communicates with machine B but he does not know that fact.
it did not open a tcp connection on machine B so I would expect to receive RST from machine B.

this is not the case - I noticed in the debug capture log that host x retransmits 10 times and only then machine B sends RST.

Can someone explain what happended and why machine B did not send RST on the first request?

10x

Comment: Which mechanism you use for failover?

Comment: why this info required?

Comment: There are several ways to realize failover of ip adresses, depending on this there could be several reasons which leads to your problem.

Comment: mind to elaborate?
I'm not familiar with the failover method

Comment: It could be that the client still uses the old MAC from server A, if the MAC is not taken for server B than that could be the cause.